# Parse JSON Data without keynames to List of custom object

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Using [`datatables.net`](http://datatables.net/) in `MVC4`, I'm trying to pass my sorted/rendered data from the datatable to my controller `ActionResult` using jQuery AJAX POST. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "urlGoesHere",
     dataType: 'JSON',
     data: "{'jsonString':'" + JSON.stringify(data) + "', 'someParams':'" + someParamsVar + "'}",
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
});
```

In my Controller, using NewtonSoft's library, I'm trying to convert the posted data:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string jsonString, string someParams)
{
    List<myObjectName> requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myObjectName>>(jsonString);
}
```

However, `jsonString` value seems to be a JSON array without key names. How can I convert this to List? Tried different way of serializing, but none of those give me progress.

Here's my sample JSON string:

```
[
    [
        "1",
        "01/09/2013",
        "04/09/2013",
        "07/09/2013",
        "lexeRoy"
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "02/09/2013",
        "03/09/2013",
        "04/09/2013",
        "myName"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would deserialize a one dimensional array. It should work for any nested arrays.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

string json = "" +
                "  [" +
                "     \"Steve\"," +
                "     \"was\"," +
                "     \"here\"" +
                "   ]" +
                "";

String[] data = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<String[]>(json);
```